# Any idea to fix the github project download

Tags: angular, git, github

i add to git version a proyect in  a other pc with git commands:git commit/ git remote add origin https://.../myuser/proyecname.git/ git push -u origin master. And Its ok at the moment
But when try to download in VisualStudioCode i get error in some files. In the principal file 'angular.json' i have a warning line

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
```

and i notice that I don't have the node_modules in my project, then i try run:

```
npm run ng clean
```

but i have and error
[image]

after i run:

```
npm run ng install
```

[image]

i do not why this problem

Comment: if you don't have `node_modules`, then run `npm i`

Comment: i retry to open again VSCode,, the files look fine, but its do not run yet, attach the video here: http://srecorder.com/uploads/2020-06-30_18.29.56.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You do **ng** for Angular specific commands whereas install is node package manager(npm) specific.

So, you can directly write `npm install` instead of `npm run ng install`

And, for running `npm run ng clean`, you have to define what clean needs to be done in your **package.json**.

It will be something like this :

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "ng serve",
      ......
      ......
      "clean" : "--- write what needs to be done here---"
}
```

Comment: right, it works! . i use npm run because in my other proyects its can´t exec with ng serve only. i usually write npm run ng serve. but thanks @Akhil

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the ✔ icon below the question to close the loop. 

Comment: however,i have a mistake, i delete the package-lock.json ; the console adverticement :created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file. Now my proyect doesn´t detect changes in git

Comment: Package-lock has nothing to take with tracking changes in git.

Comment: There is a folder named .git which actually maintains the unstaged/modified files

Comment: There must be no issue if you delete a package-lock, when you do npm install.. A new lock file gets generated and you can commit that

Comment: ok, thanks, well its extrage, i run GitHubDesktop app and since explorer this i could send my chages and pulls, then the App ask me open VSCode and its work in git version